# return the bucket number where the given word is located

Tags: c++, hashmap, unordered-map, bucket

I am working on a project and I'm having trouble understanding this.
I have an unordered map and I named it `Hash`.

The goal is to come up with two separate functions that return the bucket number where the given word is located. I know that for one function I can do something like `return Hash.bucket(word);` But, I saw somewhere online someone did this instead:

```
if(Hash.count(word)!=0)
    return Hash.bucket(word);
```

Why did they compare it to 0?

Also, are there any other ways I can do this besides using `.bucket()`?

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Comment: I recommend talking this one through with [your Rubber Duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). While Duckie's specialty is debugging, he's also pretty good at helping you interpret the logic behind other people's code.

Comment: It depends on the context.  Certainly, if the hash table can potentially be empty, then some sort of test is required (although in that case it's more appropriate to use `bucket_count` because it doesn't require an actual lookup).  Basically, the behavior of `unordered_map::bucket` is undefined if there are no buckets.  The only other reason I can think of is the code you saw expects that if this function returns a valid bucket number, then it guarantees the word is actually in the container.  Just calling `bucket` alone does not guarantee this.

Comment: As of C++20, you can write `if (Hash.contains(word))...` instead of using `.count(word) != 0` - just a smidge more direct and readable.  *"are there any other ways I can do this besides using .bucket()"* -> nothing better / there are crazy options like brute force iteration over the buckets and bucket-content

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand it, they compared it to zero so that you would be able to make sure it actually exists in the map. If you `return Hash.bucket(word);` on something you haven't put into the map, it will still return the bucket of what the key's hash would correspond to. The function does this without checking if the word already exists in the map or not. The if statement ensures that you only get it's bucket if you know it is already in there.

I don't know of a different way to get the bucket number off the top of my head.

Comment: *"it will still return the bucket of what the key's hash"* - some typo in there as it doesn't make sense, but you seem to understand what it will do: return the bucket identified by a combination of applying the hash function to the key and the mapping function (`%` or `&`) into the bucket_count, i.e. proper place to insert or look for that key.

Comment: I think I reworded that part so it was a bit more clear. Thanks my dude.